# Wordpress - How to skip the search result page and directly jump to the first result

Tags: wordpress, search

I am creating a shipment tracking site using wordpress.
Is there a way to jump to the first result without seeing the result page?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `search.php` or `searchform.php` file in your theme, you can just remove the `while()` loop so that WP only displays the first result.

```
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    the_post();
    // Include your template for displaying content here
else : 
    // Display no post found notice
endif;
```

Note that this will override ALL search form results, so if you have other search forms in different places that need to return multiple results, then you will need to add some logic to handle both cases.

Comment: thanks for your effort. I've edited 'searh.php' here is my code:
'
<?php
  if ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
   // Display Post Content
 get_template_part( 'template-parts/content','post' );
  else :
   ?>

   <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></p>
   <?php
    get_search_form();

  endif;
  ?>
'
Problem 1: it does show post content
Problem 2:  even if i type some content into the php file, it will only display on the right half of the screen instead of whole page.